# Media queries not reacting

Tags: media-queries

I use some media queries on my Wordprees site, and firstly they worked, but now they first react later than

```
@media screen
and (min-width:250px)
and (max-width:921px) {
.ejer-thumbnail {
width: 20%;
}
}
```

When I make my browser (chrome) to 920px nothing happens... The images is the same size.
It first react on the browser at 829px

Comment: When you look in inspector (with F12) and select the image, does it show a crossed out "width: 20%;", or does the "width: 20%;" never appear? This affects where the problem is.

Comment: It show width:20%; when browser is smaller than 829 px.
But the @media say (max-width:921px)

Comment: Is this your only media query, or is there another one that may be interfering?  Also, do you have any Javascript that could be relevant (such as if you are also resizing the element with javascript)

Comment: Also you said "firstly they worked, but now they first react later" do you mean that at one point the same code for your media query was working exactly how it should? Because if so, then that definitely points to something interfering like in my comment above.